# Text render has weird shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shadows

I made a super basic design just a 2 texts with curve modifier. But when I render it (cycles mode) it has weird shadows.

[image]

I tried to adding smooth modifier, edge split modifier, increasing sampling changing font and changing lights but they didn't work.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your mesh might not be flat in those areas.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to BSE. There is a good chance that it is a normals issue, so go to _Toolshelf > Shading/UVs > Normals:_ and click on _Recalculate_. If this doesn't help, please consider uploading your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), BSE's very own .blend hosting site.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Thank you but sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: The issue is related to how text is filled as a surface. It is done using a 'scan fill' method, meaning the surface is made with lots of horizontal lines, which isn't the best geometry for bending. Short answer: convert to a mesh and retopologise, maybe by using the remesh modifier as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because text object, being a bezier curve of sorts, is filled with triangulated faces on  the tops. You text object then seems to be curved backwards causing the triangulation to become visible.

It appears to be  actually a problem of lack of subdivisions and bad topology.
This is one of the reasons quad based topology is always preferred, but in the case of bezier curves this is not possible without destructively converting it to mesh.

Make a copy of your text object if you haven't already (keep the original somewhere) and then try converting it to a mesh. Then either add a *Subdivide* modifier (this alone won't totally fix the problem) or manually remove all the top triangulated faces and try to fill them with a more uniform quad based grid where possible, or ideally do  both, so the curve modifier has more geometry to operate on.

[image: Fix text topology]

Only then on top of the fixed mesh apply your curve deformation.