# Wrinkle Surface

Tags: mesh, shaders

[image]

I made this mesh extruding a svg curve from Ilustrator. The idea, as you can see on the modifiers panel is to bend it. I understand that for this I need to divide the face with edges so that I can bend the face. I did it but still get wrinkles so I took them of and tried to clean every vertice on the mesh.

[image]

What I'm asking is if there's a way to fill the face with quads (and if thats the solution) so that I can bend the mesh and correct all the wrinkles in the shading.

Here is the [project file](http://[%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6643%22%20/%3E](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6643/)).

Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70656/how-to-reduce-artifacts-on-curved-text-vector https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42571/better-curve-text-to-mesh-generation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56083/text-render-has-weird-shadows/56091#56091

Comment: Thank you Duarte!